# Reset current display index to first element in Pnp Carousel

Tags: typescript, react-native, carousel, spfx

I am using Pnp-SFX Carousel control in my react app.
Here I am displaying Carousel like below:

```
                        <Carousel
                            buttonsLocation={CarouselButtonsLocation.center}
                            buttonsDisplay={CarouselButtonsDisplay.block}
                            containerButtonsStyles={styles.carouselButtonsContainer}
                            isInfinite={false}
                            interval={null}
                            startIndex={this.state.startIndex}
                            prevButtonStyles={styles.preSlide}
                            nextButtonStyles={styles.nextSlide}
                            indicatorShape={CarouselIndicatorShape.circle}
                            indicatorClassName={styles.customIndicator}
                            element={this.state.allItems} // applying JSX element
                            onMoveNextClicked={(index: number) => { }}
                            onMovePrevClicked={(index: number) => { }}                       
                        />
```

I am setting the **this.state.startIndex** to '0'.
I have dropdown also to filter to display to the specific element in the Carousel items on its change event. The event is triggering fine and filtering element in the Carousel by filtering in the **this.state.allItems**

But the Carousal is not displaying the element if we are not in the first element of the Carousel. But the filtered element is there in the 0th  index element.

Kindly help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting **both** `allitems` and `startIndex` at once (may be a bug though, try reporting in the [github repository](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-controls-react))

```
setState({ startIndex: 0, allitems: youritems.filter(....) })
```